Prometheus data point disappears if not in the last scrape (getting around staleness)
We're monitoring a Hashicorp Vault instance which reports the number of entries in each kv engine by namespace. Works fine when the data is reported however, sometimes the report comes back empty but it hasn't been 5m yet. My understanding is that the value may not be updated each time a scrape runs if the value has not changed since last scrape.
I had read that if the last scrape did not contain the key, then the last value was always available and would be reported back but it seems not so?
Here is the setup: Prometheus is running in a docker container, with latest tag.
These two queries are ~6 minutes apart, and the query was working fine for a while before it show any data for this key only for a couple of minutes.


The startup options:
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=90d

The scrape job runs every 2m with a default timeout.

Docs "If a target scrape <..> no longer returns a sample for a time series that was previously present, this time series will be marked as stale."

@markalex I understand. I was asking if there is anything I can do to get the data to be not stale.

Regarding fixes: proper one - fix exporter to expose data properly. Workaround - instead of metric use something like last_over_time(metric [15m])
